# How do I add different icons to treeview items in a wpf application using xaml?

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a treeview which has been populated using a dataset. Now I need to add different icons to the treeview nodes. How do I add them using xaml?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a custom template for the TreeViewItem like this:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                 
                        <CheckBox Tag="{Binding}" />
                        <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CustomImagePathConvertor}}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Comment: But won't this apply the same image to all treeview items? My real problem is to change the icon of the treeview item based on a user action like say right click.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `Image Path` and use `Template` to implement it:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" ClickMode="Press">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Grid Height="16" Width="16">
                            <Image x:Name="imgBkg" />
                        </Grid>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="imgBkg" Value="/XXXX;component/YourImage.png"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```